# Bootstrap modal-body – disable closing with ESC key or mouse

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How Can I disable modal-body from closing, please note that I can't use modal class or modal fade.
Im suing two pages one have a href and on click go to another page have the modal:

```
<td align='center'  span style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="save_new.php</a></td>
```

so here my code

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#myModal').modal({
backdrop: 'static'
    });
});
</script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal-body">
<button  class = "btn btn-success" ><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Done</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Javascript:

```
$('#modal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

As HTML:

```
<a data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

Comment: this is wont work, class in my code is modal-body wish you have a solution

Comment: can you post your full? it will be easier to understand and provide you the solution.

Comment: I am a little confused because your code doesn't define proper bootstrap modal, so $(..),modal({}) won't work and that is the reason why backdrop and keyboard properties are not working

Answer (score -1):

Adding the attributes of `data-keyboard="false"` and `data-backdrop="static"`  to your modal `<div>` will keep the escape key from closing the window.